# Incorrect records count in javascript

Tags: javascript, extjs

I use Ext.PagingToolbar (Sencha JS) and have next code:

```
 bbar : [ {
xtype : 'paging',
store : store,
displayInfo : true,
pageSize : 25,
displayMsg: 'Displaying {0} - {1} of {2}',
prependButtons : true
```

In case when i have two (or more) records, then result has next view - "Displaying 1 - 2 of 3"
How i can fix it?

Store proxy:

```
store = new Ext.data.GroupingStore({
    pageSize: pageSize,
    autoDestroy : true, 
    proxy : new Ext.data.HttpProxy(
            {
                url : 'delinquent/cas.html',

                listeners : {
                    exception : function(self, type, action, options,
                            response, arg) {
                        if (type == 'response') {
                            App.ui.error("Data load error");
                        } else if (type == 'remote') {
                            App.ui.error('Error', response.raw.message);
                        } 
                    }
                }
            }), 
    reader : new Ext.data.JsonReader({
        totalProperty : 'results',
        root : 'info',
        fields : [ 'id', 'createdAt', 'createdBy', 'cName',
                'cF', 'region', 'statusId', 'sN', 'dls', 
                'cS', 'updatedat', 'updatedby' ]
    }),
    sortInfo : {
        field : 'createdAt',
        direction : 'DESC'
    },
    groupField : ''
});
```

Comment: Are you sure that fields config is supported by Ext.data.JsonReader? and check server response, should be like {info: '', results: 2}

Comment: Agree with **Dart** here. You shouldn't be setting fields on a reader, that isn't a supported config. Let's see your actual server response, otherwise it's hard to help.